# The website can't be logged in using mobile devices

Tags: php, mobile

I'm now constructing a website in mobile version and it's like `www.example.com/m/` . And now I got a problem which is I can't login the website using mobile devices(Android, iPhone, iPad).

However, it works under following situation:

1. login the website using mobile device on `localhost`
2. login the website using laptop on `localhost`
3. login the website using laptop on `server`

That's mean it only doesn't work when I use mobile device to login on the server.

```
$dbCon = dbConnect::create();

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//================= Loading Member Informations==================================== 
$sql = "select * from members where (phone = '$login' or email = '$login') and password = '$password' limit 1";

if ($result = mysqli_query($dbCon,$sql)) {

  $rows_num = 0;                                             //record?

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows_num++;

      //================== Get Member data ===================================================
      $user_id = $row['id'];                      
      $display_name = (empty($row['display_name']))? $row['name'] : $row['display_name'];       
      $email = $row['email'];       
      $phone = $row['phone'];       
      $email_confirm = $row['email_confirm'];    
      $member_type = $row['member_type'];     
      if($email==$login){ $loginby = 'email'; }elseif($phone==$login){ $loginby = 'phone'; }
      //==================================================================================

    //================ Remember me ================================
    if($_POST['remanber_me']=="on"){    
        setcookie("user_id",$user_id,time()+60*60*24*30);
        setcookie("display_name",$display_name,time()+60*60*24*30);
        setcookie("email",$email,time()+60*60*24*30);
        setcookie("phone",$phone,time()+60*60*24*30);
        setcookie("email_confirm",$email_confirm,time()+60*60*24*30);
        setcookie("loginby",$loginby,time()+60*60*24*30);
        setcookie("member_type",$member_type,time()+60*60*24*30);
    }
    //================================================================

    //================= SESSION==========
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $_SESSION['display_name'] = $display_name;  
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;      
    $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;      
    $_SESSION['email_confirm'] = $email_confirm; 
    $_SESSION['loginby'] = $loginby;
    $_SESSION['member_type'] = $member_type;  
    //===========================================

    //======================== Update last login time ===============================
    $sql = "update members set last_login_time = NOW(), last_login_ip = '$ip' where id = $user_id";
    $dbCon->query($sql);
    //======================================================================
}
```

On the abover script, it can update the user last login information. So that currently I guess the problem was on the `sessions`. However, I have no idea how to actually solve the problem...

EDIT: When I do `print_r($_SESSION)` and `print_r($row)` within the while loop, It has record. But when the script redirect back to `index.php` or the other pages, It's still haven't logged in the website.

Also, when I login `www.example.com` first, and then go back `www.example.com/m/`, it can still keep my login status...I just can't login directly through `www.example.com/m/`..

Comment: You need to debug it yourself first. When logging in using your phone, does `$result` has any records? Dit you start the PHP session?

Comment: @redelschaap I'm so sorry about  that. I have edited my question.

Comment: My best guess is that the script above is reached when loading your site root only, and not when browsing to `/m/`. What do you get when using `print_r($_SESSION)` at the top of you application, right after `session_start()`?

Comment: @redelschaap The problem is solved...See my own answer below. I just made a careless mistake. Thanks you very much anyway...

Comment: Glad you could solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright...I just found that I missed another `$_SESSION` variable..so normally it should be:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
$_SESSION['display_name'] = $display_name;  
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;      
$_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;      
$_SESSION['email_confirm'] = $email_confirm; 
$_SESSION['loginby'] = $loginby;
$_SESSION['member_type'] = $member_type;  
$_SESSION['action_time'] = time(); //the stuff i missed
```

So it cause the user logout automatically after he has logged in the system...

It was really a careless mistake...I should remind myself not to do this again...